# animating a ball in borland graphics c++

Tags: c++, bgi, borland-c++

I am trying to animate a football that i have drawn using the borland graphics interface (BGI). User input will be taken to determine the position of the ball. So far I have drawn the ball but am not sure how to write a second function that will change the position of a ball given user input.

I only want to move the ball in the x-direction of a cartesian plane. To do this I've tried to add the user input to any of the aspects of the ball that contain an x-coordinate but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the function that draws the football:

```
void Football::drawBall()
{

  int x = OFFSET + 900;
  int y = (HEIGHT / 2);
  int rX = 80;
  int rY = 50;
  setcolor( BLACK );
  setfillstyle( SOLID_FILL, BROWN );
  fillellipse( x, y, rX, rY );

  setcolor( BLACK );

  int xI = OFFSET + 860;
  int yI = (HEIGHT / 2);
  int xF = xI;
  int yF = yI;

  // Horizontal Lace on Ball
  line( xI, yI, xF + 80, yF );

  // Vertical Laces on the Ball, starting from the left

  for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
  {
    line( xI + (20*i) , yI + 5, xF + (20*i) , yF - 5 );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Animations in Borland C++ can be achieved by drawing, then erasing, then redrawing using updated coordinates.

You can the ball by drawing it, then erasing it (drawing over itself in the background color), drawing the ball using different coordinates.

Following is the sample code:

```
void Football::drawBall(int nOffset)
{

  int x = nOffset + 900;
  int y = (HEIGHT / 2);
  int rX = 80;
  int rY = 50;
  setcolor( BLACK );
  setfillstyle( SOLID_FILL, BROWN );
  fillellipse( x, y, rX, rY );

  setcolor( BLACK );

  int xI = nOffset + 860;
  int yI = (HEIGHT / 2);
  int xF = xI;
  int yF = yI;

  // Horizontal Lace on Ball
  line( xI, yI, xF + 80, yF );

  // Vertical Laces on the Ball, starting from the left

  for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
  {
    line( xI + (20*i) , yI + 5, xF + (20*i) , yF - 5 );
  }
}

void Football::eraseBall(int offSet)
{

  setcolor(BLACK) // Assuming this is the background color.

  int x = nOffset + 900;
  int y = (HEIGHT / 2);
  int rX = 80;
  int rY = 50;
  setcolor( BLACK );
  setfillstyle( SOLID_FILL, BLACK );
  fillellipse( x, y, rX, rY );

  setcolor( BLACK );

  int xI = nOffset + 860;
  int yI = (HEIGHT / 2);
  int xF = xI;
  int yF = yI;

  // Horizontal Lace on Ball
  line( xI, yI, xF + 80, yF );

  // Vertical Laces on the Ball, starting from the left

  for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
  {
    line( xI + (20*i) , yI + 5, xF + (20*i) , yF - 5 );
  }
}
```

Now simply call these functions one after the other in a loop:

```
Football fb = new Football();
int nLoop = 0;

for(nLoop=0; nLoop < 50; nLoop++)
{
  fb.drawBall(nLoop);

  /* The delay value is in milliseconds. 
     Increase it to make the ball animate slower. 
     Decrease it to make the ball animate faster. */
  delay(200); 
  fb.eraseBall(nLoop)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `drawBall` method needs x,y coordinates from either the `Football` class or via arguments.  The code you pasted shows hard-coded coordinate.

You may want to consider drawing the ball into a bitmap (sprite), then pasting the bitmap instead of drawing the ball all the time.  Most graphics chips can copy a bitmap from memory and display it on the screen ("blitting"), more efficiently than you can draw, fill, then draw again.

Once you have a bitmap, moving is a matter of:
1. Erase present bitmap.
2. Draw bitmap and new location.
3. Delay.
4. Repeat.